# How can I undo input value by rolling back the previous valid value in Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, validation, kendo-ui

I have an input component as the following:

```
<input type="number" value="0" name="weight" format="0" min="50" max="100">
```

What I expect:

1. input a number between 50 and 100, for example 70;
2. focus other component then focus back on this input;
3. input a number which is lower than 50 or greater than 100, for example 20;
4. focus other component
5. I expect the box rolling back to 70 instead of populating 50, the min attribute.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
var ntb = $("#num").kendoNumericTextBox({
    min : 50,
    max : 100
}).data("kendoNumericTextBox");

var oldvalue = undefined;
$("#num").on("focusin", function(e) {
    oldvalue = $("#num").val();
});

$("#num").on("focusout", function(e) {
    var value = $("#num").val();
    if (value < ntb.options.min || value > ntb.options.max) {
        $("#num").val(oldvalue);
    }
});
```

Basically you intercept the `focusin` event and save previous value and in `focusout` you check that are inside the limits, if not, you restore the old saved value.

**EDIT** If you need to do the same for many input fields in the page, what you can do is:

```
// Save old value in the numeric text box by adding an oldvalue property to it
$("[data-role='numerictextbox']").on("focusin", function(e) {
    var me = $(this).data("kendoNumericTextBox");
    me.oldvalue = $(this).val();
});

// Restore saved old value if value is not in range
$("[data-role='numerictextbox']").on("focusout", function(e) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var me = $(this).data("kendoNumericTextBox");
    if (value < me.options.min || value > me.options.max) {
        $(this).val(me.oldvalue);
    }
});
```

See it running here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/yYX7m

Comment: Thank you very much, OnaBai. That does work. But I have tons of inputs and pages. Could it be a generic method?

Answer (score 0):

There is a field named "_old" in the KendoNumericTextBox object; this is useful for this purpose, at least when handling a NumericTextBoxSpinEvent, *viz.*:

```
function spinEventHandler(e) {
    alert("delta from spin is: " + (+e.sender._value - e.sender._old));
}
```